# How do I automatically set the version of my Inno Setup installer according to my application version?

Tags: inno-setup

I am using Inno Setup to generate the installer of my application. How can set the version number of the setup.exe (`VersionInfoVersion`) generated by Inno to match with the version number of my application automatically? Now every time I deploy a new version of my application I need to update the version number manually.

Now I'm doing this:

```
[Setup]
VersionInfoVersion=1.2.2.0 //writing the value manually
```

I want something like this:

```
[Setup]
VersionInfoVersion={Get the version of my app}
```

Answer (score 111, accepted):

You can use the Inno Setup Preprocessor `GetVersionNumbersString` function like this

```
#define ApplicationName 'Application Name'
#define ApplicationVersion GetVersionNumbersString('Application.exe')
[Setup]
AppName={#ApplicationName}
AppVerName={#ApplicationName} {#ApplicationVersion}
VersionInfoVersion={#ApplicationVersion}
```

Comment: Oh it seems I needed to put in the complete path to my exe... not just the name of the exe as in the example.

Comment: why isn't it possible to use `#define ApplicationVersion GetFileVersion({#ApplicationName})` ?

Comment: @NickG: relative path is also sufficient

Comment: @SAAD: it should work: `#define ApplicationVersion GetFileVersion(ApplicationName)`

Comment: In case you have relative folder specified separately, the correct syntax would be: `#define MyAppVersion GetFileVersion(MyAppSourceFolder + '\' + MyAppExeName)`. It is important to remember that `{#var}` syntax doesn't seem to work here.

Answer (score 17):

Another way to do it by using [a command line argument](http://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/topic_isppcc.htm) :

```
[Setup]           
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
```

and you just call your script as follow from a cmd :

```
cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5

iscc /dMyAppVersion="10.0.0.1" "C:\MyPath\MyScript.iss"
```

It emulate `#define MyAppVersion="10.0.0.1"` in the iss script.

---

If you are using [CakeBuild](http://cakebuild.net/), you can pass this argument as

```
 string CurrentVersion  = "10.0.0.1";
 InnoSetupSettings settings = new InnoSetupSettings();
 settings.Defines=   new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
            { "MyAppVersion", CurrentVersion },
            };
   InnoSetup("C:\MyPath\MyScript.iss", settings);
```

Answer (score 6):

In case you have a pure webinstaller, the accepted solution won't work, 
because you simply won't have an application.exe to get the version number from.

I'm using **Nant** and a `build.xml` file with version number properties, which i manually bump, before i'm rebuilding the innosetup installers.

My *.iss files contain a special token @APPVERSION@, which is replaced
with the version number during the build process. This is done via a copy operation with an applied filterchain, see below.

**InnoSetup Script (*.iss)**

```
// the -APPVERSION- token is replaced during the nant build process
#define AppVersion "@APPVERSION@"
```

**nant build.xml:**

```
<!-- Version -->
<property name="product.Name"           value="My Software"/>
<property name="version.Major"          value="1"/>
<property name="version.Minor"          value="2"/>
<property name="version.BuildNumber"    value="3"/>
<property name="product.Version" 
          value="${version.Major}.${version.Minor}.${version.BuildNumber}"/>

<!-- build task -->
<target name="bump-version"
        description="Inserts the current version number into the InnoScript.">
        <copy todir="${dir.Build}" overwrite="true">
            <fileset basedir="${dir.Base}/innosetup/">
                <include name="product-webinstaller-w32.iss"/>
                <include name="product-webinstaller-w64.iss"/>
            </fileset>
            <filterchain>
                <replacetokens>
                    <token key="APPVERSION" value="${product.Version}"/>
                </replacetokens>
            </filterchain>
        </copy>
</target>
```

Answer (score 4):

I had some problems with getting this to work, so just contributing my solution.

app.iss:

```
[Setup]
#include "Config.txt"

#define AppVersion GetFileVersion("Input\" + AppExec)


AppName={#AppName}
AppVersion={#AppVersion}
```

Config.txt:

```
#define AppName "App"
#define AppExec "App.exe"
```

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, the [`GetFileVersion`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=getfileversion) or [`GetStringFileInfo`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=getstringfileinfo) preprocessor functions can be used for that.

Some important info, improvements and helpful additions:

- You can either use an absolute path to the exe, or a path ***relative to the .iss file***
- You can include existing defines in your statement by just writing their name, and concatenate defines with the `+` operator:
  `#define MyAppPath "..\Win32\Release\" + MyAppExeName`
- If you want you can easily remove parts of the version number from the right by using the function `RemoveFileExt`, e. g. convert 3.1.2.0 to 3.1.2:
  `#define MyAppVersion RemoveFileExt(GetFileVersion(MyAppPath))`
- You can use the defines `MyAppExeName` and `MyAppPath` in the subsequent options like `Messages`, `Files` or `Icons`

Working example:

```
#define MyAppName "Application Name"
#define MyAppExeName "Application.exe"        
#define MyAppPath "..\Win32\Release\" + MyAppExeName
#define MyAppVersion RemoveFileExt(GetFileVersion(MyAppPath))

[Setup]
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
VersionInfoVersion={#MyAppVersion}
OutputBaseFilename={#MyAppName}-{#MyAppVersion}-Windows

...

[Messages]
SetupWindowTitle=Setup - {#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}

...

[Files]
Source: {#MyAppPath}; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion; Tasks: desktopicon

...

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
```

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I would like to define the version string from a file.  I don't have an EXE, since my installer is packing an embedded Python program.  So I define the version number in a one-line text file like such (this is created from a `git tag` statement beforehand):

> ..\Build\app_version.txt:
> v1.2.1

In the Inno Setup, I used a pre-processor define statement to set the version throughout the text.

```
#define VerFileNum FileOpen("..\Build\app_version.txt")
#define MyAppVersion Trim(StringChange(FileRead(VerFileNum),"v",""))
```

Here, I used `Trim()` and `StringChange()` to remove the leading "v" and trailing spaces from the string.  Later in the setup section, the `AppVersion` value can be set using the pre-processor definition:

```
[Setup]
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
```

The Inno Setup pre-processor has quite an extensive set of functions already defined: [Inno setup pre-processor functions](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php)

Answer (score 1):

After quite some time trying other methods, the way it worked for me was to use a relative path (I have the .iss file in a folder and the EXE file two levels above).

```
; Extract File Version from EXE
#define MyAppVersion GetFileVersion("..\..\Release\CSClave.exe")
```