# Passing in version number to Inno Setup compiler

Tags: inno-setup

I want my Inno Setup script to be build using the command line, and I want to pass in the product version number as a parameter. I am trying to implement it like so:

```
[setup]
VersionInfoVersion={param:version|0.0.0.0}
```

However the compiler informs me this is invalid for that directive. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3618257/is-it-possible-to-accept-custom-command-line-parameters-with-innosetup) post on how to pass in custom parameters from the command line and assume I should just be able to pass in something like:

```
compil32 /cc "c:\isetup\samples\my script.iss" /version=1.0.0.0
```

I have also tried the suggestion from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6498750/how-do-i-automatically-set-the-version-of-my-inno-setup-installer-according-to-m) and tried doing the following:

```
#define PathToMyBinary "C:\bin\x64\Release"
#define ApplicationVersion GetFileVersion('#PathToMyBinary\MyBinary.dll')

VersionInfoVersion={#ApplicationVersion}
```

But it doesn't seem to return anything. Both approaches seem valid to me so I'm hoping someone can explain where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming you define the version via a pre-processor variable like:

```
[Setup]
VersionInfoVersion={#ApplicationVersion}
```

---

To set the version on a command-line, you have to use the [`ISCC.exe` command-line compiler](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=compilercmdline) and its [`/D` switch](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=isppcc):

```
ISCC.exe Example1.iss /DApplicationVersion=1.2.3.4
```

---

If you want to provide a default value for the version, so the script can compile even without defining the variable on the command line, use [`#ifndef`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=ifdef) at the *top* of the script:

```
#ifndef ApplicationVersion
#define ApplicationVersion "1.2.3.4"
#endif
```

---

To read the version from a binary, you are correctly using the [`GetFileVersion` pre-processor function](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=getfileversion).

But your syntax to make up the path is wrong.
A correct syntax is `PathToMyBinary + '\MyBinary.dll'`, like:

```
#define PathToMyBinary "C:\bin\x64\Release"
#define ApplicationVersion GetFileVersion(PathToMyBinary + '\MyBinary.dll')
```

See [Inno Setup Preprocessor: Expression Syntax](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=expressions).

Comment: I'm now setting the version using the pre-processor function GetFileVersion and it is working now that I am using the correct syntax, thanks.

Comment: In the docs they show what exactly is happening with the parameter. Ex. `/D<name>[=<value>] Emulate #define public <name> <value>`

Answer (score 4):

After looking at many different options I found that this worked for me.

This is the command line to compile the setup file

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\iscc.exe" "MySetup.iss" /DVersion=1.2.3.4
```

In the setup file I added these lines, the first lines are to enable you to still run the script in the editor and ensure you would not get the error: Undeclared identifier: "Version"

```
#ifndef Version
  #define Version = '0.0.0.0';
#endif

[Setup]
VersionInfoVersion={#Version}
```

Comment: True. Though a more common syntax is `#define Version '0.0.0.0'` (no equal sign and no semicolon)

Answer (score 0):

In order to get my setup script (iss file) to work, I had to remove the #define ApplicationVersion line from my script.  Once I did that, it recognized my /DApplicationVersion=8 input parameter.

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Inno Setup 5\iscc.exe" "install.iss" /DApplicationVersion=8