# How to pass parameter value from compiler to the script?

Tags: inno-setup

I need to pass a parameter value from compiler to the `[Files]` section of my compiled script, such as one can do at setup runtime using the `{param:...}` constant in their script. My idea is compiling my script e.g. this way (which fails to execute):

```
compil32 "script.iss" -CmdPath "D:\Samples"
```

Having in my script something like this (it won't work as it's for setup runtime not compilation time):

```
#define DefPath "D:\Install"

[Files]
Source: {param:CmdPath|DefPath}\Install\App.exe; DestDir: {app};
```

Comment: See also [Passing in version number to Inno Setup compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36449026/850848).

Answer (score 2):

You can build your setup by using ISCC compiler passing it the path through the `/D` parameter. That will declare a public `#define` for your script. Since the `#define` can be redeclared by the script, you need to ensure its conditional declaration for the default value you want to have. For example:

```
#ifndef SrcPath
  #define SrcPath "C:\DefaultPath\"
#endif

[Files]
Source: {#SrcPath}App.exe; DestDir: {app}
```

Then building the setup this way will use the `#define` from the script:

```
ISCC.exe Script.iss
```

Whilst building it this way will use the `#define` declared by the passed parameter value:

```
ISCC.exe Script.iss /DSrcPath="C:\AnotherPath\"
```

Comment: Welcome back to SO!