# Inno Setup constants and parameters

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to add a parameter to my setup file, with a default value.
In this case I get a compile error at

```
OutputBaseFilename=MyApp {param:Version|{#MyAppVersion}} Setup
```

Saying:

> Value of [Setup] section directive "OutputBaseFilename" is invalid

Shortened reference code:

```
#define MyAppName "My App"
#define MyAppVersion "1.7.24"

[Setup]
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion="{param:Version|{#MyAppVersion}}"
DefaultGroupName=VHStudio
OutputBaseFilename=MyApp {param:Version|{#MyAppVersion}} Setup
SetupIconFile={#PathToRepoRoot}\Development\VHS\VHSStudio\media\logo.ico

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\VHStudio {param:version|MyAppVersion}"; Filename: "{app}\VHStudioApp.EXE"; WorkingDir: "{app}"
Name: "{group}\Uninstall VHStudio"; Filename: "{app}\unins000.exe"; WorkingDir: "{app}"
Name: "{userdesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\VHStudioApp.EXE"; Tasks: desktopicon
```

I'm guessing I'm using the constant wrong?
The Strange thing is that I do

```
AppVersion="{param:Version|{#MyAppVersion}}"
```

Without any errors...

Comment: I want to build the installer via the cmd and I want to pass the version to it through the parameters. The ```OutputBaseFilename ``` should change accordingly (ex. "MyApp 1.7.17 Installer")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comment from Martin. Suggesting to take a look at [Passing in version number to Inno Setup compiler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36449026/passing-in-version-number-to-inno-setup-compiler).

Turns out I overcomplicated things. You can easily pass parameters to the compiler for pre-processor variables. In my situation `MyAppVersion`.

What I did in Inno Setup:

```
#ifndef MyAppVersion
  #define MyAppVersion "1.7.24"
#endif
```

And when compiling it looks like this:
`ISCC.exe myProg.iss /DMyAppVersion=1.7.14`