# Inno Setup: How to update AppVersion [Setup] value from Config.xml file

Tags: xml, windows, inno-setup

I want to update `AppVersion` value in `[Setup]` section at compile time from `config.xml` file by parsing `Version` tag.

`Config.xml` file has below configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Configuration> 
  <Version>1.0.1</Version>
</Configuration>
```

My application is using `config.xml` file for application version. I also want to use the same version in Inno Setup installer version.

I am new in Inno Setup script development. It would be very helpful if someone provide me right approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a simple PowerShell code like:

```powershell
$version = ([xml](Get-Content 'config.xml')).Configuration.Version
Set-Content -Path 'version.txt' -Value $version
```

And run it using [Inno Setup preprocessor](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/):

```
#define RetrieveVersion(str FileName) \
  Local[0] = AddBackslash(GetEnv("TEMP")) + "version.txt", \
  Local[1] = \
    "-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command """ + \
    "$version = ([xml](Get-Content '" + FileName + "')).Configuration.Version;" + \
    "Set-Content -Path '" + Local[0] + "' -Value $version;" + \
    """", \
  Exec("powershell.exe", Local[1], SourcePath, , SW_HIDE), \
  Local[2] = FileOpen(Local[0]), \
  Local[3] = FileRead(Local[2]), \
  FileClose(Local[2]), \
  DeleteFileNow(Local[0]), \
  Local[3]

[Setup]
AppVersion={#RetrieveVersion("C:\path\config.xml")}
```

---

For a similar question, see [Read application version from a text file in Inno Setup](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63464800/850848).

---

Though I assume that the application compiler actually uses the `config.xml` for the application executable version. If that's the case, you can retrieve the version from the .exe more easily.

See [How do I automatically set the version of my Inno Setup installer according to my application version?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6498750/850848)