# Inno Setup: Overriding [Setup] parameters based on user-defined functions

Tags: installation, inno-setup, pascalscript

I am trying to configure `AppVersion` parameter in `[Setup]` section based on a string which is stored in an external text file.

To accomplish that; I tried to write a function which opens that external file and returns the version; So that later I can utilize the returned version for setting multiple parameters.

```
#define APP_NAME "blah blah"
#define APP_VERSION "4.0.1"

[Setup]
AppName={#APP_NAME}
;;; AppVersion={#APP_VERSION} ;;; This works
AppVersion=GetVersion() ;;; This does not work as I am expecting

[Code]
; Basic example
function GetVersion(): string;
var 
  FileLines: TArrayOfString;
begin
  Result := '1.1.1'
end;
```

However, this did not work. Inno Setup did not execute the function. It actually used the function name (i.e. `GetVersion()`) as the version itself.

**My question:** Does Inno Setup support such behavior?

---

**Update:** I figured out that I can get the version from EXE itself instead of opening a text file and reading the version from it.

```
#define NAND_DECODER_VERSION GetFileVersion("dist\*.exe")
```

Comment: Where does the file exist? On the machine where you compile the installer? Or on the machine where you install the installer?

Comment: It exists on the machine where I compile the installer; Actually - For simplicity - I placed both external file and *.iss in the same directory.

Answer (score 2):

[Constants](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts), including [scripted *"constants"*](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants), are evaluated on run-time (install-time).

If you need to run a code on compile-time, you need to use the [preprocessor](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/).

Some related questions with examples:

- [How do I automatically set the version of my Inno Setup installer according to my application version?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6498750/850848)
- [Inno Setup: How to update AppVersion [Setup] value from Config.xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46929344/850848)

Comment: I tried  AppVersion={code:GetVersion} and it worked. Thanks a lot

Comment: So either I did not understand your question or you did not understand my answer. You wrote that the file *"exists the **machine where [you] compile the installer**"*. So you cannot use `{code:...}`. It may work with `Result := '1.1.1'`. But it won't work, if you want to access a file on *"the machine where [you] compile the installer"*.

Comment: ooh,,, i did not read the file yet; But I executed the function and it returned '1.1.1'  and assumed file will also work,,,, I don't understand why it won't work on file yet

Comment: As my answer say in the very first sentence. The code runs on run-time (install-time), so it cannot access a file that exist on compile-time.

Comment: Final solution was to use GetFileVersion(..) API to read the EXE version .....      
 #define NAND_DECODER_VERSION GetFileVersion("dist\*.exe")"