# How do I automatically set the version of my Inno Setup installer according to the latest git describe command?

Tags: git, exe, inno-setup

I found this question, which is similar –
[How do I automatically set the version of my Inno Setup installer according to my application version?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6498750/13131950#6498791) – setting installer version based off application version. I want to set based off the `git describe` command.

I did try the help described in the link I attached, however my version appears blank when I adapt the example code into mine. I don't know how to set this version in the executable – which is why I want to grab it from `git`. Seems either `git` or the executable are good places to grab the version, unless someone can describe otherwise for me. If setting the executable version is better, how do I do that?

My question: How do I automatically set the version of my Inno Setup installer according to the latest `git describe` command?

Answer (score 1):

This is much closer to what you need:
[Inno Setup: How to update AppVersion [Setup] value from Config.xml file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46929344/850848)

---

- Write a PowerShell (or any other) script that can save the version number retrieved from `git describe` to a text file.
- Use the [`Exec` preprocessor function](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=exec) to execute your script (or if you have an overall build script, just have it generate the text file before you run the `iscc` compiler).
- Then you can use the [`FileOpen`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=fileopen) and [`FileRead`](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=fileread) preprocessor functions to inject the information into your `.iss` script.

Answer (score 1):

You can obtain the SHA1 hash of the last commit using the following command:

```
git.exe log "--pretty=format:%H" -n 1
```

The result can be written to file like this:

```
git.exe log "--pretty=format:%H" -n 1 > revision.txt
```

Using Inno's preprocessor, this can be done on the fly like this:

```
#define GetRevision() \
  Local[0] = "/S /C git.exe log ""--pretty=format:%H"" -n 1 > revision.txt", \
  Local[1] = Exec("cmd.exe", Local[0], SourcePath, , SW_HIDE), \
  Local[2] = FileOpen(AddBackslash(SourcePath) + "revision.txt"), \
  Local[3] = FileRead(Local[2]), \
  FileClose(Local[2]), \
  Local[3]
```

Finally, you can use the hash anywhere you want in your setup script, e.g. like this:

```
[Setup]
VersionInfoProductTextVersion={#GetRevision()}
```